# Issue while copying files having filenames with foreign character in Linux

Tags: java, linux, encoding, character-encoding

I am writing java program and trying to copy files from one folder to another in Linux. But for some files i am getting NoSuchFileException exception 
while copying files having french character in filename.

```
Actual Filename : NéwlyCreâtêd.csv
```

But in linux instead of foreign charaters it is automatically replacing with (?) question mark and getting No Such file exception.

```
Exception:
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /data/N?wlyCre?t?d.csv
```

Earlier i got this issue in windows also but i have tried to change file encoding to `-Dfile.encoding=IS-8859-1` and it works fine in windows.
But in linux still it is not working even i tried to change file encoding.

can you please help to resolve the issue. Even if there is any foreign characters i need to copy from one folder to another folder.

Comment: use `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i tried that too but still it is not working.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to keep the non-ascii characters? If not, I'd recommend converting the filename

Comment: The file is given by business and we should not allowed to change the file name.

Comment: You could use .listFiles() on the data directory (as a File) and capture the files with special characters in a list of File objects? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Tried to use .listFiles() but still it is not working.